# Reuse the same expensive calculations in select and filter statement in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgvector

Is there a way to reuse calculations in sqlalchemy such as `SUM` if I want to get the `SUM` and filter by it, or do I not need to worry of such things?

In my case I'm using `pgvector` to get the id of previous transactions which has a cosine-similarity above 0.8 e.g:

```py
session.execute(
        select(model.identifier, 1 - model.embedding.cosine_distance(source_embedding)).
              filter(1 - model.embedding.cosine_distance(source_embedding) >= 0.8).
              order_by(model.embedding.cosine_distance(source_embedding)).asc()
              ).limit(5)).all()
```

As you can see the `model.embedding.cosine_distance` is invoked multiple times; in `select`, in `filter` and in `order_by` and can be a rather costly operation. Is there a way to do that smarter or is that handled automatically?

Comment: Use a [CTE](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#common-table-expressions-ctes)?